# Proxying maven central snapshots leads to "Remote disabled automatic routing" error in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, maven-central

My project uses an open source framework I have written. The latest version of the framework is in maven central, but we need its latest snapshot version. The snapshot version can be found in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

We am using an installation Sonatype Nexus in the project as a mirror of everything (*). In Nexus I have defined a proxy-repository with repository-policy snapshot to the above link. The public repositories group contains that proxy-repository.

Unfortunately routing for that proxy-repository fails in Nexus with "Remote disabled automatic routing" and the build fails since it can't find the frameworks snapshot version in the repository.

How can I access a snapshot version of a framework stored in central via my Sonatype Nexus instance? According to https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide#SonatypeOSSMavenRepositoryUsageGuide-7a.2.PublishSnapshots this should be possible.

Answer (score -1):

In your proxy repository configuration is a "Repository Policy" drop down -> you need you choose "SNAPSHOT" there.